# Codeception with Yii2, Acceptance testing : Explicit wait InvalidElementStateException

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, yii2, webdriverwait, codeception

I'm trying to execute an acceptance test on a form inside and Iframe.
My test seems to be a flaky test, in fact using the same configuration and same script, my test sometimes is successful and sometimes fails .
To overcome this issue I'm trying to use the Explicit waits from Codecption :https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#waitForElementVisible.
This condition sometimes works and sometimes, the element takes longer than 60 seconds to load.

```
 $testXpath1 ="//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']";
 $I->waitForElement(['xpath' =>$testXpath1 ], 60);
 $I->fillField(['xpath' =>$iframeXpath1],'ggggggggggggg');
```

This is a sample of a successful run :

```
 Scenario --
    Destroying application
    Starting application
    [ConnectionWatcher] watching new connections
  [Fixtures] Loading fixtures
  [Fixtures] Done
  [TransactionForcer] watching new connections
 I am on page "/#/pages/practice/iframe-form"
  [GET] https://rori4.github.io/selenium-practice/#/pages/practice/iframe-form
 I switch to i frame {"xpath":"//iframe"}
  Failed to find locator by name: Array to string conversion
  Iframe was not found by name, locating iframe by CSS or XPath
 I wait for element {"xpath":"//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']"},60
 I fill field {"xpath":"//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']"},"ggggggggggggg"
 I wait for element {"xpath":"//label[@for='i9']"},60
 I click {"xpath":"//label[@for='i9']"}
 I click {"xpath":"//div[@jsname='d9BH4c']"}
 PASSED
```

This is an example of a Failed run :

```
 [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidElementStateException] Element is disabled: \<input class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" type="text">
Scenario Steps:

     4. $I->fillField({"xpath":"//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']"},"ggggggggggggg") at tests\acceptance\IframeCest.php:19
     3. $I->waitForElement({"xpath":"//input[@aria-labelledby='i1']"},60) at tests\acceptance\IframeCest.php:17       
     2. $I->switchToIFrame({"xpath":"//iframe"}) at tests\acceptance\IframeCest.php:15
     1. $I->amOnPage("/#/pages/practice/iframe-form") at tests\acceptance\IframeCest.php:13
```

I'm new to Codeption with Yii2 using Selenium webdriver, I'm more familiar with SeleniumWebdriver with Python and Javascript.

So I wanted to know if there is a corresponding method in CopdeCetion to the wait.until using the expected conditions in Javascript or Python, because I don't want to enter a specific time ,I just want to make sure that my element is present and clickable for example :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);

//presence in DOM
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(By.id("ID")));`enter code here`
```

Comment: I'd advice you to accept giving you answers and upvote the, This may increase your chances for getting an answers here...

Comment: @Prophet, I'm not sure I got your answer , can you please clarify more. thank you

Comment: I'm talking about your previously questions. There were several ones that got answered but you didn't accept them. So there are several users that are checking for the asker's history before giving the answers...

Comment: Got you @Prophet, thanks for the advise , I'm trying to mark us much as I can.